# How to use if else condition ,while iterating through a dataframe column,in order to club values and create a new column?

Tags: python, pandas

`dataset['Age'].value_counts()`

```
output i get:36-55-MATURED VOTER           492
             24-35-YOUNG VOTER             341
             56 Above-EXPERIENCED VOTER    182
             18-23-NEW VOTER                77
             70                              5
             60                              5
             68                              4
             65                              3
             63                              3
             62                              3
             75                              3
             72                              1
             69                              1
             67                              1
             80                              1
             

             73                              1
             66                              1
             Name: Age, dtype: int64'
```

Here `dataset['Age']` is a column of the dataframe dataset. I am trying to create a new column within.

The same dataframe called `dataset['Age in Num']`, where all the original values would be grouped into

```
#just 4 categories
18-23-NEW VOTER      as  18 
24-35-YOUNG VOTER    as 24
36-55-MATURED VOTER  as 36
the remaining values as 56
```

I used the following code, but it didn't work...

```
for Age in dataset['Age']:
    if Age == '24-35-YOUNG VOTER':        
       dataset['Age in Num'] = 24
    elif Age == '36-55-MATURED VOTER':
        dataset['Age in Num'] = 36
    elif Age == '18-23-NEW VOTER':
        dataset['Age in Num'] = 18
    else:
        dataset['Age in Num'] = 56

#then when i typed dataset['Age in Num']
#i got this 

0       36
1       36
2       36
3       36
4       36
5       36
6       36
7       36
8       36
9       36
10      36
11      36
12      36
13      36
14      36
```

All the values as 36 only.... Thank-you for any help

Comment: If we can't read your code, we can't help you. See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/628368)

Answer (score 0):

That's what you are looking for:

```
def test(Age):
if Age == '24-35-YOUNG VOTER':        
    return 24
elif Age == '36-55-MATURED VOTER':
    return 36
elif Age == '18-23-NEW VOTER':
    return 18
else:
    return 56

df['Age in Num']=df.Age.apply(lambda x: test(x))
```

Output (Example):

```
   Age                Age in Num
0   1                   56
1   32                  56 
2   24-35-YOUNG VOTER   24
3   24-35-YOUNG VOTER   24
4   36-55-MATURED VOTER 36
5   18-23-NEW VOTER     18
```